# Condition of lines that are results of perspective transform

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, line, perspective, homography

I have set of lines that have been transformed using a perspective transformation.
The information that I know about these lines are:

- They are lines not line segments (no length or start point or end point is known)
- They are all parallel
- Distances between them are unknown and vary from pair to pair.

[image: Imaginary image of origin and result]

So, to make it clear again, I do not know the blue lines. I have just the greens. Even, I do not know what is the Homograph Matrix that was applied.

**Question:**
I need a method, a measurement, an algorithm or even a hint about the condition that must all the green lines satisfied.

For example if I add this red line to the set:
[image: Noisy line added]

It is obvious that the red line could not be exist in the set of lines before applying the transformation so it is a noise of course.
So I need a measurement if I applied it on the green lines would give me positive response and if add the red line to the green set it would show a negative response or at least a lower confidence.

P.S. OpenCV is available and preferred.

Comment: if you find the source that a perspective homography gives the same result as a 3d projection of a plane you'll find that vanishing points: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanishing_point will be present after perspectively transforming parallel lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are parallel before perspective projection all lines should intersect in the same vanishing point. I would say you should compute this point using your green lines (maybe [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61719/finding-the-intersection-point-of-many-lines-in-3d-point-closest-to-all-lines) is helpful) and if the [distance from your red line to the vanishing point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line) is to big it can be rejected.

Comment: Thanks.. "If they are parallel before perspective projection all lines should intersect in the same vanishing point". May you point me where you could find this information if possible (I am not in doubt I am just want to know the source so I can read more)

Comment: BTW if the transformation was just a rotation which is a small case of the perspective. They will still be parallel. is is a special case? in other words the condition will be: if they are parallel or they intersect in the same point?

Comment: I can recommend [this](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/hzbook/) book. You'll find everything in detail in the section "Vanishing points and vanishing lines" (Or Wikipedia about vanishing points). To be honest, I assumed your given, general case. For sure there are some degenerated perspective transformations, e.g mapping everything to single a line. A rotation is a special case yes. But the condition remains. They still have the same vanishing point, but its at infinity. Using homogeneous coordinates you can handle that too.

Comment: you are totally right it is not an exception it is the same.. Many thanks you helped me a lot